# does minecraft optifine 1.7.10 work with 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine

The title says it all, folks. does the minecraft download optifine 1.7.10 work with 1.8? And what is the difference between the Optifine light version and the Optifine HD Ultra?

Comment: probably not, the obfuscation of minecraft will likely change and make the interface invalid

Comment: @ratchetfreak lol what's obfuscation?

Comment: Give it a try and let us know but the answer is most likely No.

Comment: is the download a .jar? I thought it was a .zip ...

Comment: lol... I just downloaded it and installed it... and it erased EVERYTHING in my inventory?!?! how to fix?

Comment: @HandofDon Did you make a backup? If not, then that stuff is gone. Always make a backup before installing mods. (Because you never know when a mod is going to break everything)

Answer (score 5):

Sadly no. But Optifine has just released a standalone version that will work with Minecraft 1.8. No need to run forge or anything.

**How To Install Optifine for Minecraft 1.8**

Here is a tutorial I made showing you [how to install Optifine for Minecraft 1.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxxQ953Upt4)

1. Download Optifine for 1.8 from [here](https://optifine.net/downloads)
2. Activate the Jar file you have downloaded, This will install Optifine automatically.
3. Open your Minecraft launcher and select the newly created "Optifine" profile
4. Start Minecraft and enjoy playing with Optifine.

Answer (score 0):

No. Optifine 1.7.10 is made for 1.7.10 and not for 1.8. Wait a bit until it is updated. Optifine light has less features, and ultra has more. I know this isn't a very complete answer but its all i know!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, [Optifine](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1272953-optifine-hd-a4-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af-and) isn't available for Minecraft 1.8, But they are updating it:

> Update to 1.8 is in progress: ---%

If you wan't to use optifine in Minecraft 1.8, all you need is just some patience.

The differences between between the Optifine versions are:
[image: Differences]